# Does Flutter suppors BLE on Windows platform?

Tags: windows, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter-dependencies

Flutter is starting to give support to the Windows platform now. Is there an option available to integrate BLE for Windows desktop apps?

Comment: Flutter is just a UI toolkit. If you want something like BLE support, you can use or write a plugin that wraps the BLE API in Dart.

Comment: The team of the flutter_blue plugin are working on it: https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/330 There is a similar issue for flutter_react_ble

Answer (score 0):

`DeviceInfo()` where is this class.

```
onDeviceTap(BleDevice device) {
   /* Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DeviceInfo(
            device: device,
          )),
    );*/
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).